# Add new contact view controller set up iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Hi I am trying to learn how to create an simple app that would benefit from the set up of Apples add a new contact view. With the ability to add Names and press the button to add more phone numbers. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Do they just use a bunch of table views? Also how do they have so many different sections. Sorry if this is a easy thing to create. I am new to app development.

Comment: go through the UITableView tutorials. You only need one tableview with editing mode and check editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Thank @jpulikkottil I understand that part but how to they have the layout with certain text fields with letters and numbers and the button to add a new text field and they even have a to have a specific ringtone. Is that all through only one table view?